# BAPI для SAP EWM

Tags: sap

Нужно в SAP EWM изменить данные по материалу программно, а именно профиль адаптации и номер складского места.
Кто знает BAPI для реализации этой истории?

Comment: BAPI_PRDSRVAPS_SAVEMULTI2 - если что, нашел)

Comment: Номер складского места где где хранится материал?